# Making markers clickable in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I'm struggling to make the markers on [this Mapbox map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/scroll-driven-navigation/) clickable without destroying the scrolling effect. I want to make it possible to click on one of the markers, and then be scrolled to the right section.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your javascript:

```
 /* Bind event handler to the featurelayer that holds the markers */
placesLayer.on('click', function(e) {
    //Get the id of the clicked marker
    var id = e.layer.feature.properties.id;

    //Scroll to the element
    document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1oxkgfkw/

NOTE: As is, the code posted in the mapbox example won't work because of of their css definition for 'article'. You have to remove `right:0` as I did in the jsfiddle so the article element doesn't cover the screen and prevent clicks from registering on the markers.